# Equivalent mysql to eloquent query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to transform this query to the equivalent in Eloquent.

```
SELECT country_id, count(*) as count
FROM seeds
WHERE seeds.created_at > date_sub(NOW(), interval 24 hour)
GROUP BY country_id
```

What I have so far.

```
$seed = Seed::select('*')->where("created_at", ">", DB::raw('(NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)'))
        ->get();
```

I can't seem to group them country_id and add a count column that says how much there is of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better readability, try combine with Carbon too, which is included with Laravel.

```
Seed::select(array(
    'country_id',
    DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count'))
->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subHours(24))
->groupBy('country_id')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `groupBy` method, all of the methods are here: http://laravel.com/docs/queries (well, most of them).

```
$seed = Seed::whereCreatedAt('>', DB::raw('(NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)'))->groupBy('country_id')->get();
```

If you wanted a count you can just do `$seed->count()` from here, and if you wanted a list of the `country_id` you could do `$seed->lists('country_id')`.

Hope that helps.